# How to update button color variable in alertDialog?

Tags: android, flutter, android-alertdialog

I'm new here and I'm having a problem with the alertdialog.
Type I have an alertdialog that has a select color button and that already comes with a pre set color, this button leads to another alertdialog that makes the color selection. After selecting this new color, returns to the first alertdialog and the button should come with the new color, but this does not happen.
Thank you very much. And do not call English, because I'm using a translator.

```
Future<Color> selectColor(BuildContext context, Color currentColor){
  Color selectedColor = currentColor;
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context){
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Selecionar Cor'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: BlockPicker(
            pickerColor: currentColor,
            onColorChanged: (Color color){
              selectedColor = color;
            },
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[

            FlatButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pop(context,selectedColor);
              },
            )
          ],

      );
    }
  );
}

Future<List> createCategory(BuildContext context) async{

  String name = '';
  Color selectedColor = BLUE;

  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Nova Categoria'),
          content: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                  flex: 4,
                  child:
                  TextField(
                    maxLength: 30,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Nome'
                    ),
                    onChanged: (String value){
                      name = value;
                    },
                  )
              ),

              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
              ),

              Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child:
                  RaisedButton(
                      color: selectedColor,
                      onPressed: () async{

                        selectedColor = await selectColor(context, selectedColor);

                      }
                  )
              )
            ],
          ),

          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('CANCELAR'),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pop(context, null);
              },
            ),

            FlatButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: (){
                //print('cor '+selectedColor.toString());
                Navigator.pop(context,[name,selectedColor]);
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      }
  );}
```

Comment: are you using setState? Use setState to chance a variable that will update the UI.

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo I have tried using setState, but it gives error, because I would be trying to store in a variable of type Color a value of type Future <Color>.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be occurring because you not using setState function which will update the UI if some changes occurred, in this case colour value is changing. so

Replace below code

```
BlockPicker(
        pickerColor: currentColor,
        onColorChanged: (Color color){
          selectedColor = color;
        },
      ),
```

with this one

```
BlockPicker(
        pickerColor: currentColor,
        onColorChanged: (Color color){
              setState(() {
                   selectedColor = color;
              });
        },
      ),
```

Comment: It did not work very well, because now it only updates when I touch the TextField

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and testing, find out what the problem was. Is that for every alertDialog for data transeference would have to create a new class of type StatefullWidget. I'll leave the code as it was.

```
    //In main
    Future<List> createCategory(BuildContext context) async{
      return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => CreateCategory()
      );
    }

class CreateCategory extends StatefulWidget{
  CreateCategory ({Key key}) : super (key: key);
  _CreateCategoryState createState() => _CreateCategoryState();

}

class _CreateCategoryState extends State<CreateCategory>{
  String _name = '';
  Color _currentColor = BLUE;

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Nova Categoria'),
      content: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
              flex: 4,
              child:
              TextField(
                maxLength: 30,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Nome'
                ),
                onChanged: (String value){
                  _name = value;
                },
              )
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
          ),

          Flexible(           
              child:
                FlatButton(
                  color: _currentColor,
                  shape: CircleBorder(), 
                  child: null,
                  onPressed: selectColor,
                )   
          )
        ],
      ),

      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('CANCELAR'),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context, null);
          },
        ),

        FlatButton(
          child: Text('OK'),
          onPressed: (){
            //print('cor '+selectedColor.toString());
            Navigator.pop(context,[_name,_currentColor]);
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void selectColor() async{
    final selectedColor = await showDialog<Color>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => SelectColorPickerDialog(currentColor: _currentColor,)
    );

    if(selectedColor != null){
      setState((){
        _currentColor = selectedColor;
      });
    }
  }

}

class SelectColorPickerDialog extends StatefulWidget{
  final Color currentColor;

  SelectColorPickerDialog ({Key key, this.currentColor}): super (key: key);

  @override
  _SelectColorPickerDialogState createState() => _SelectColorPickerDialogState();
}

class _SelectColorPickerDialogState extends State<SelectColorPickerDialog>{
  Color _color;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _color = widget.currentColor;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Selecionar Cor'),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: BlockPicker(
          pickerColor: _color,
          onColorChanged: (Color color){
            setState(() {
              _color = color;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[

        FlatButton(
          child: Text('OK'),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context,_color);
          },
        )
      ],

    );
  }
}
```